How to access secure variable in condition property of Powershell task in Azure pipeline
I access a secret value using AzureKeyVault@2 in a step prior then use PowerShell@2 command to execute a PowerShell script. I want to execute this step conditionally.
Here is a variable (key) I fetch a secret from Key Vault. This a variable beacuse, It will vary depending on environment.
variables:
  DefaultConnection : 'dynamic-key-dev'

I'm able to retrieve the secret using
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
   inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure Key Vault Service Connection'
    KeyVaultName: 'kv-example-kv'
    SecretsFilter: ${{ variables.DefaultConnection }}
    RunAsPreJob: false

Now I want to conditionally execute the next step provided the secret contains specific keywords
- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: contains("$env:MY_MAPPED_SEC"), 'must-contain')
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "Do Something with $env:MY_MAPPED_SEC"
    env:
      MY_MAPPED_SEC: $(${{ variables.DefaultConnection }})

condition fails to evaluate to true, Without condition, I have verified that $env:MY_MAPPED_SEC is mapped and retrieved correctly from KV.

Conditions are evaluated to determine whether to start a stage, job, or step. Therefore, nothing computed at runtime inside that unit of work is available.
In other words, giving that the environment variable MY_MAPPED_SEC is set inside the PowerShell@2 task, it cannot be used as condition for the task itself.
So instead of:
- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: contains("$env:MY_MAPPED_SEC"), 'must-contain')
  # ...

Try something like (not tested):
- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: contains(variables['${{ variables.DefaultConnection }}'], 'must-contain')
  # ...


This worked! Thanks.

Based on your YAML sample, the evaluation of the condition will be before setting the task environment variable, so the environment variable cannot be read correctly in condition.
In addition to the method shared by Rui Jarimba, I would like to share another method.
If you need to map the secret variable to Pipeline environment variable and do the next actions, you can add an additional step to using logging command to set the variable to map the secret variable to Pipeline environment variable.
For example:
- powershell: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MY_MAPPED_SEC]$(${{ variables.DefaultConnection }})"

Here is YAML example:
variables:
  DefaultConnection : 'dynamic-key-dev'
steps:
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure Key Vault Service Connection'
    KeyVaultName: 'kv-example-kv'
    SecretsFilter: ${{ variables.DefaultConnection }}
    RunAsPreJob: false
- powershell: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MY_MAPPED_SEC]$(${{ variables.DefaultConnection }})"
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "Do Something with $env:MY_MAPPED_SEC"
  condition: contains(variables['MY_MAPPED_SEC'], 'must-contain')

Result:

In this case, you can directly use the mapped variable(e.g. $(MY_MAPPED_SEC)) in the next steps without adding them to task env field.
